# Android Gradle Flavors has any apk size impact?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I'd like to use gradle flavors to have many apps in one project because the entire logic is the same, with some small changes. As we know, to declare different resource per app - we use different `/res` folder to overwrite default ones, for example:

```
      app/
    |--libs/
    |--src/
       |--my_app_1/
       |  |--res/
       |     |--layout/
       |     |  |--activity_main.xml
       |--my_app_2/
       |  |--res/
       |     |--layout/
       |     |  |--activity_main.xml
       |--my_app_3/
       |  |--res/
       |     |--layout/
       |     |  |--activity_main.xml
       |--main/
          |--java/
          |  |--...
          |--res/
          |  |--layout/
          |  |  |--activity_main.xml
          |  |--...
          |--AndroidManifest.xml
```

When I do app build I select to do it for `my_app_1` but I don't know if Android will use `my_app_2` and `my_app_3` files in apk creation process. Any advances are appreciated

Comment: No it will not use my_app_2 and my_app_3 resources while creating your APK. I will use only main and your chosen Flavor.